# Multi-Thread Member Variable vs Static Variable, How do they work differently in multi-thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I did a quick test against member variable and static variable, I found a interesting result, if a variable is member variable of static object that is always rightly calculated even in thread racing context, but if a variable static variable, it will run into problem.

For Example:
[image]

[image]

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var locker = new object();
        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(64, 64);
        var numOfThreads = 64;


        WaitHandle[] waitHandles = new WaitHandle[numOfThreads];

        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (long i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++)
        {
            var handle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
            waitHandles[i] = handle;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
            {

                obj.run();
                ((EventWaitHandle)handle).Set();
            }, handle);
            //obj.run();
        }
        WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles);
        sw.Stop();


        Console.WriteLine($"Exit Performance test {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} output: {obj.x}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static MyClass obj = new MyClass();
}

class MyClass
{
    private object locker = new object();
    //public static int x = 0;
    public int x = 0;
    public void run() {
        //lock (locker)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10000000; j++)
            {
                x = x + 1;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}, count of loop: {x}");
        }
        var f = 0;
        Console.WriteLine($"id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}, $$start: {f}");
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000000; j++)
        {
            f = f + 1;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}, $$end: {f}");

    }
}
```

As my understanding static object and it's member fields has 1 copy of instance in memory shared by multi-thread, so it should be the same as using static varialbe, but somehow it's behave differently.

Question:
1. what's the difference between static field and member field in multi-threads?
2. does that mean static field is running faster than member field?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use Interlocked.Increment in this case. For more complex types, use locks or some other means of thread synchronization to avoid having multiple threads work with shared resorces in parallel.

Comment: Please don't ever post screenshots of code - post code itself.

Comment: @Evk Sure I will do it

Comment: I tried to run your code, I have the same behavior whether `x` is static or not. Are you sure you didn't also uncomment the `lock (locker)` statement when you tested with static member?

Answer (score -1):

1. what's the difference between static field and member field in multi-threads? 
   I found for small loops member field hardly run into the multithread racing issue, but for big loops 10000000, both of them run into racing issue, so locker is required for both of them.
2. does that mean static field is running faster than member field?
   I found with locker is faster than without locker for writing into shared resource.